# visual paradigm, reverse engineering PHP project

Tags: php, reverse-engineering, visual-paradigm

I get the following error when trying to do reverse engineering with visual-paradigm:

> Reason : Error occured when analysis: includes/config.php. Encountered
>   "define" at line 6, column 66

this is the line:

```
defined('DB_SERVER')                    ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
```

Does someone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems weird.  Normally when I do short if/else in that fashion, I render the value to a variable.  Change it up to use a proper if.

```
if(!defined('DB_SERVER')) define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
```

**EDIT**
This is probably a better way maybe?

```
defined('CONSTANT') or define('CONSTANT', 'SomeDefaultValue');
```

Took from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php#84439

Answer (score 0):

Use define('DB_SERVER') not defined('DB_SERVER'), i think so

Comment: `defined('DB_SERVER')` is checking if `DB_SERVER` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ternary condition:

```
 (defined('DB_SERVER'))? null:define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
```